# tableHeaderView's height changing to 0 when navigationBar is not translucent

Tags: swift, autolayout, height, navigationbar

So I have a view called ViewHeader that I'm loading from nib and that I'm setting as the tableHeaderView. This code is in the TableViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //some other code
    addTableHeaderView()
}
fileprivate func addTableHeaderView(){
    if let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(Constants.VIEW_HEADER, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? ViewHeader {
        headerView.setTitle(titleText: TITLE)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }
```

Everything was working fine until I removed the translucent property from the storyboard for the navigationBar: The headerView stopped showing.

If I print the frame of the tableHeaderView in addTableHeaderView() the height is 30. If I print it in cellForRowAt indexPath it shows as 0.

Anybody guesses why the height is changing to 0?

And yes, I'm using Auto Layout. Anything else you need to know tell me please.[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the translucent property back to see what happens? Also can you  upload a picture of your storyboard hierarchy and autolayout constraints?

Comment: @Jake well it simply shows up again. I attached the storyboard of my tableViewController

Comment: do you have any constraints set?

Comment: @Jake no i don't